# Why anchor tag is taller when it's display:inline-block

Tags: html, css

I have an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/d7gujhLL/

You can see that the second red is taller than the first one.

is there a way to make them the same height?

```
<p style="background-color:blue">
<a style="background-color:red" href="">Inline</a>
</p>

<p style="background-color:blue">
<a style="background-color:red; display:inline-block" href="">Inline-block</a>
</p>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple way to make them the same height. The height of the inline anchor is the based on the font metrics. It's the height from the top of the ascender to the bottom of the descender. Although that is a multiple of the font-size, each font may have a different multiple.

The height of the inline-block anchor is based on the line-height. This too can be set as a multiple of the font-size, but to make them the same height, you'd have to set the multiple to be exactly the same as that of the inline anchor. Which means inspecting the font metrics of the chosen font for your anchor to discover what that multiple is.

Comment: I was trying to find a constants to set the line-height. However it seems to be changing all the time. Is there anyway that is more correct to get this number? Otherwise I think I'll just use a close one under Chrome in normal resolution.

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing extra space from the line-height.

Set `line-height: 1`.

Comment: I usually just set `line-height: 1` to `body` as per this [article](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/)

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/d7gujhLL/4/, line-height:1 still doesn't make them the same height.